# How can I apply a global QListView style to a QListWidget that uses a QAbstractItemDelegate for customized item display?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have successfully created a QListWidget that displays 2 lines of text for each item using this code (adapted from [this example](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27777-Customize-QListWidgetItem-how-to)):

SessionListDelegate.h

```
#ifndef SESSIONLISTDELEGATE_H_
#define SESSIONLISTDELEGATE_H_

#include <QPainter>
#include <QAbstractItemDelegate>

class SessionListDelegate : public QAbstractItemDelegate
{
public:
    SessionListDelegate(QObject *parent = 0, QStyle *style);
    virtual ~SessionListDelegate();

    void paint (QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const;
    QSize sizeHint (const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const;
private:
};

#endif /* SESSIONLISTDELEGATE_H_ */
```

SessionListDelegate.cpp

```
#include "SessionListDelegate.h"

SessionListDelegate::SessionListDelegate(QObject *parent)
: QAbstractItemDelegate(parent)
{
    this->_parent = parent;
}

void SessionListDelegate::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    QRect r = option.rect;

    QPen fontPen(QColor::fromRgb(51,51,51), 1, Qt::SolidLine);

    if(option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
    {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.color(QPalette::Highlight));
    }
    painter->setPen(fontPen);

    QString date = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    QString description = index.data(Qt::UserRole).toString();

    int imageSpace = 10;

    r = option.rect.adjusted(imageSpace, 0, -10, -30);
    painter->setFont(QFont( "Lucida Grande", 24, QFont::Normal));
    painter->drawText(r.left(), r.top(), r.width(), r.height(), Qt::AlignBottom|Qt::AlignLeft, date, &r);

    r = option.rect.adjusted(imageSpace, 30, -10, 0);
    painter->setFont(QFont( "Lucida Grande", 18, QFont::Normal));
    painter->drawText(r.left(), r.top(), r.width(), r.height(), Qt::AlignLeft, description, &r);

}

QSize SessionListDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
   return QSize(200, 60); // very dumb value
}

SessionListDelegate::~SessionListDelegate()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

Calling code in mainapp.cpp:

```
ui.myList->setItemDelegate(new SessionListDelegate(ui.myList));
```

Now, in the main QWidget form of my application UI, I have defined a style sheet which contains a style for all QListViews for the form:

```
QListView::item:selected {
color: black;
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 80, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
}
```

I would like to apply this style to the customized ListWidget, but I can't think of a way to make that happen. It seems like it should be a pretty common thing to do, but I can't find any examples anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should inherit from [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstyleditemdelegate.html) instead of `QAbstractItemDelegate`. From the Qt documentation:

> Since Qt 4.4, there are two delegate classes: QItemDelegate and
>   QStyledItemDelegate. However, the default delegate is
>   QStyledItemDelegate. These two classes are independent alternatives to
>   painting and providing editors for items in views. The difference
>   between them is that **QStyledItemDelegate uses the current style to
>   paint its items. We therefore recommend using QStyledItemDelegate as
>   the base class when implementing custom delegates or when working with
>   Qt style sheet**

Comment: Thanks -- that's it. I actually did find an example just before reading your response at http://qt-articles.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-customize-listview-in-qt-using.html that shows this in action.